# Альтернатива капче

Tags: php, captcha

Возьмём, к примеру, тот же free-lance.ru, когда пользователь авторизируется, его не просят вводить капчу. Какой там способ от ботов используется?

Какая есть альтернатива капче, которая даёт 100% защиту? (горшочковый метод, метод блокировки по ip - всё это не даёт 100% защиты). Как защититься от ботов, не используя капчи при авторизации?

КАК ТОГДА free-lance.ru защищается. При АВТОРИЗАЦИИ у них нет капчи?

Comment: при регистрации вы имели ввиду?

Comment: @Артур Лоденев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

- Можно прикрутить сервис отправки смс,
     если позволяют средства , копеек 40
     за 1 смс при малом бюджете, при более
     большом можно до 20 копеек взять
- Можно вопрос вводить или число указанное при регистрации, что-то типа проверки на человечность.
- Так же вместо капчи (если посмотреть на некоторые сайты) предлагают выбрать картинку из списка, соответствующей тематике. Либо повернуть все картинки строго по вертикале, скрипт готовый уже где-то лежит.
- Для извращения можно юзеру при регистрации давать скачать файл(в файле какой-то хеш или что-то без разницы что, но с инфой именно по его данным) ну и если это реальный юзер,  он постоянно носит флешку с файлом с собой. При авторизации он этот файл скармливает системе и получается некий ключ доступа. Но это извращение :)

При авторизации тут все просто, проверяем логин и пароль, если 3-5 раз ввел неправильно, отсылаем письмо на указанную почту письмо, что кто-то пытается войти и не удается. Аккаунт блокируем. Разблокировка по ссылке в письме, там же и ссыль на напоминалку пароля.

**//upd** *дальше писать или 3-4 пунктов хватит? У меня воображение суровое и постоянно приходят мысли?*

Comment: Поддерживаю - контрольный вопрос лучашя альтернатива капчи.

Comment: :)
вспомним гугль.

У него есть ф-я двойной авторизации. Тебе на трубу приходит код, который указываешь и входишь! Это кстати очень удобно.

Comment: довольно спорная, кстати

надо и чтобы пользователь догадался что от него хотят и сломать было трудно

такое не так часто встретишь

Comment: 2 @AlexAndR ну если пользователь захотел зарегиться на вашем ресурсе, значит он должен быть в теме. Значит он должен логически догадаться, либо должна присутствовать подсказка(и) для различных полей, чтобы заполнение последующих не вызывало проблем.

Да и при заполнении чтобы он сам запоминал что куда ввел. Отослать можно всю инфу на почту в каком-нить формате.

Comment: >довольно спорная, кстати
>надо и чтобы пользователь догадался что от него хотят и сломать было трудно такое не так часто встретишь

а тут на помощь, придет отправка смс'ки  ;)

Comment: От SMS спама чрезычайно сложно избавиться.

Comment: А еще можно сделать как на [braingames.ru][1], тогда еще и по IQ фильтр будет.  
[1]:http://www.braingames.ru/?path=registration

Comment: Число, вопрос — это и есть CAPTCHA. Оно не только «распознай текст с зашумленной картинки», это *любые* интерактивные автоматические тесты, предназначенные для различения автоматов и людей.

Comment: @karmadro4 стопе! Какой смс спам? Тут никто ничего не путает?

Answer (score 0):

Там нужно подтвердить свой e-mail. Если не подтвердишь, то аккаунт через несколько дней удалится автоматически

Comment: ну это, кстати, слабенькая защита, мне кажется

email почти все просят подтвердить и обычно это не отменяет капчу

Answer (score 0):

100% защиты вы не добьётесь в любом случае.

Можно использовать OpenID.

Comment: OpenId буэ... ни на одном своём сайте не использую.

Comment: я тоже, но с точки зрения пользователя оценил сервис Loginza - никакой особой информации (тот же аккаунт гугла жалко использовать), заводишь аккаунт только для регистрации/авторизации на других сайтах.

Comment: Я вот когда-то с ней тоже столкнулся. И реально понял что это ппц.

Регистрация на сайте с помощью логинзы это жесть. Аккаунт имеет вид Shreklk3j45 345345;lkjpoyegtiw что-то типа того. как потом понимать через что юзер зашел на сайт? Для меня это как-то не айсово, не могу я смотреть на имя пользователя,которое и прочитать то невозможно.

Comment: @Shrek OpenID может не нравится Вам, как разработчику, но вот пользователям это нравится. Авторизоваться в два клика, чем вспоминать что ты вводил при регистрации намного лучше.  
Особенно бесит, когда при регистрации накладывается ограничение, что пароль должен быть не менее 10 символов и "сложный", а при авторизации нигде не указывается какие были ограничения на пароль. То есть при авторизации глотает любой пароль, хоть из одной буквы. Так это сделано например на DropBox.  
>>>

Comment: >>>  
К примеру у меня стандартный пароль qwerty1234, который я использую на большинстве сайтов за аккаунт на которых я не переживаю- мне все равно если меня взломают на каком-то форуме.  
DropBox требует сложный пароль. Я ввожу QwErTy1234 - DropBox его принимает и все отлично. Проходит пара месяцев и мне надо залогиниться в DropBox- я ввожу свой стандартный пароль, но он не верный. Если бы я видел, что при регистрации от меня требовали сложный пароль, то я бы вспомнил, что вводил с разным регистром, но нет. Приходится восстанавливать пароль.  
Так что OpenID жизненно нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Мне наоборот логинза понравилась. Очень удобно.

Answer (score 0):

100% защита от ботов это миф, даже капча не дает 100% защиты, есть сервисы которые за $1 предлагают 1000 распознований капчи(отправляешь на вход картинку - тебе текст). Будьте проще при создании защиты от ботов, помните про неуловимого [Джо](http://lurkmore.to/%cd%e5%f3%eb%ee%e2%e8%ec%fb%e9_%c4%e6%ee) :)

Comment: ага, антигейт называется, только помоему не за 1 а за 10 =)

Comment: Антигейт у нас самый известный, но они не единственные :) Если верить их сайту цены не менялись.

Answer (score 0):

Предположу что:
 1. free-lance.ru идеологически не особо напрягают боты. К примеру, написал я бота который каждые 10 минут проверяет личные сообщения(забудем о том факте что уведомления о новых письмах в личке и так приходят на е-mail). Free-lance.ru сильно страдает от этого? :)
 2. Возможно free-lance.ru анализирует поведение залогиневшегося юзера и таким образом вычисляет ботов с последующим баном.